# Linking issue with "multiple definition of" compilation error

Tags: c, header, definition

I have the following "constants" header:

```
/* constants.h */

#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif

#pragma once

#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

const char * kFoo = "foo";
const char * kBar = "bar";

#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I am `#include`-ing this header in files `X.c` and `Y.c`.

Note that I am **not** including this in `X.h` or `Y.h`.

The files `X.c` and `Y.c` get compiled into object files which are archived into a static library called `libXY.a`.

When I include `X.h` and `Y.h` in `Z.h`, and when I link to `libXY.a`, I cannot compile `Z.c` without errors:

```
/* Z.h */

#include "X.h"
#include "Y.h"
```

I get the following compilation errors when trying to compile `Z.c`:

```
/path/to/libXY.a(X.o):(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `kFoo`
/path/to/libXY.a(Y.o):(.data+0x0): first defined here
/path/to/libXY.a(X.o):(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `kBar`
/path/to/libXY.a(Y.o):(.data+0x8): first defined here
```

I have tried setting `kFoo` and `kBar` to `extern`, but that does not help.

How would I resolve multiple definitions, when I am only including the constants once (via the header guard `#ifndef CONSTANTS_H`)?

Comment: Maybe not the immediate issue (not sure), but you should remove the bogus `#pragma once` and put proper multiple-inclusion guards in your header. The standard format is `#ifndef MYHEADER_H #define MYHEADER_H .... #endif`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How would I resolve multiple definitions, when I am only including the constants once (via the header guard #ifndef CONSTANTS_H)?

With this in `constants.h`:

```
const char * kFoo = "foo";
```

a definition for `kFoo` will be emitted in every translation that `#include`s `constants.h`. Thus, multiple definitions, which then result in link errors.

As asaelr noted (+1), you would solve it like this:

constants.h

```
extern const char* const kFoo;
```

constants.c

```
const char* const kFoo = "foo";
```

(note that i also made the pointer const, which is *usually* what you want to do in this case)

Comment: There are some other options that could be considered. In the current context, what you've suggested is about right, but: (A) `static const char *kFoo = "foo";` would work without a separate constants.c file; and (B) `static const char kFoo[] = "foo";` might be a more accurate rendition of what's required (and 4 or 8 bytes less space used, depending on 32-bit vs 64-bit pointers); and (C) `extern const char kFoo[];` plus constants.c containing `const char kFoo[] = "foo";` might be an appropriate variation of your solution. The code should probably not be allowed to do `kFoo = "pqr";`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler +1 I actually started to write about variations which could be made in this scenario in a follow up edit, but discarded my edits as I and others on this site have already done that. I think `extern const char* const kFoo;` is generally the clearest way (using C) to declare/document that you're dealing with a string constant. Of course, that is subjective. A+B) would work, but may result in binary bloat. the constants.h + `k` prefix suggests this is an osx or ios project (it often ends up in the pch). `extern` is typically simplest for compilation and linking in that scenario.

Comment: Unless you actually need a pointer as well as the string, use the array notation in preference to pointer notation.  I agree that the static versions can lead to code bloat and are not generally recommended.  (The pointer versions lead to code bloat, too, increasing the executable by the size of a pointer per constant.)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Not so - It's just not that simple. The array notation results in a deep physical copy *per definiton*. The pointer to the string literal results in a pointer to a constant in data - no copy is required and literals are reusable. That is to say, given: `const char A[]; const char B[]; const char* const C; const char* const D;` and with all definitions referring to one literal in one c file - `A != B`, `B != C`, yet `C == D`. Therefore, the pointer notation can certainly be lighter than the array because will reduce redundant definitions to one value while minimizing data copy

Answer (score 4):

You should not define variables in header file. define them in one of the source files, and declare them (`extern`) in the header file.

(You wrote "I have tried setting kFoo and kBar to extern, but that does not help." I guess that you didn't define them in a source file)

Comment: If I define the variables in `constants.c`, I get "undefined reference to `kFoo`" errors when compiling the library. (I am compiling `constants.c` to `constants.o` and including it with the library.) Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you define or declare it? How do you link it?