# #define or const to define constants in a C header file?

Tags: c, header

I'm writing a C header file that defines quite a few constants (mostly ints) that I use in different .m files.  I'm doing this to avoid having magic numbers all over my code.  Right now I'm using #define for this, but is it better to do it some other way?  Some other answers here seem to recommend using const to declare the constants, but when I look at some standard header files (like math.h), they use #define.

Am I even writing a header file for the right reason?

Comment: It looks like in that topic most people recommend static const, although I think they are referring to its use in a .c file.  Does that guideline still apply when declaring constants in a header file?

Comment: In a header this could be a little bit more complicated because of [multiple definition errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049320/linking-issue-with-multiple-definition-of-compilation-error). So it depends heavily on the data type. But for int's it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks.  Am I right in using a header file for this purpose?

Comment: @nonex If you're going to use these constants in more than 1 file, then yes, you are right in using a header file.

Comment: The "static const" vs "#define" in C *may not* be a valid candidate for dup, as *answers* say nothing about headers